# Componente padre no detecta evento disparado por hijo

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un componente que es una tabla y tengo un boton buscar con el siguiente evento.

Componente datatables:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" @keyup="$emit('filterSearch')" v-model="search">
```

y en el componente B importo este componente:

```
template>    
    <datatables  @filter-search="filterSearch()">
    </datatables>
</template>



<script>
    import datatables from '../tables/datatables';
    // import pagination from '../tables/pagination';

    export default {
        name: "userdraw",

        components: {
            datatables: datatables
        },
        methods: {
            filterSearch(){
                alert(1);
            },
        }
    }

</script>
```

La cuestión que cuando escribo en el input search alguna letra/palabra quiero que se ejecute un método en el componente padre, pero nunca me salta el alert de filterSearch!

Comment: No ninguno. No se que estará faltando @gbianchi

Comment: Me anduvo, interprete mal la documentación y tenia que ir los nombres iguales! gracias @gbianchi

Comment: Listo lo puse como respuesta por si le pasa a otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los nombres de los eventos en vue son declarados como vienen.

VUE transforma los nombres en mayusculas a nombres en minusculas, por lo tanto, un evento llamado `filterSearch`, se va a transformar en un evento `filtersearch` (notese la falta de mayusculas).

La documentación de VUE, recomienda usar kebab-case (esto es, separar las palabras con guiones medios) para no tener diferencias entre los mismos.

Si un nombre de evento no se llama exactamente igual al nombre disparado por el hijo, este evento no se ejecutara.

La documentación descriptiva esta [aca](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)